# table with pagination populated by drop down

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

im working on a page that populates a drop down menu, from an sql query to show vehicles that belong to a certain user. once a vehicle is selected it runs a function that opens a table with invoices tied to that vehicle. the problem is the number of invoices is rather large and i would like to use pagination to move forward and backwards through them. so far, it brings up the first page just fine. when i click next it gives me an error saying undefined index q and it also looses all my html formatting, most likely because in forwards to my getuser.php page. please take a look at my code and tell me what im doing wrong, ive been trying to get this to work for hours

source code for securedpage.php

```
<?php


include('config.inc');
include('func.inc.php');
include('db.inc.php');

$hostname = 'localhost';        // Your MySQL hostname. Usualy named as 'localhost', so        you're NOT necessary to change this even this script has already online on the internet.
$dbname   = 'ServiceHistoryDB'; // Your database name.
$username = 'root';             // Your database username.
$password = '';                 // Your database password. If your database has no password, leave it empty.

// Let's connect to host
mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or DIE('Connection to host is failed, perhaps the service is down!');
// Select the database
mysql_select_db($dbname) or DIE('Database name is not available!');


// This could be supplied by a user, for example

$username = $_SESSION['username'];

// Formulate Query
// This is the best way to perform an SQL query
// For more examples, see mysql_real_escape_string()
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM customers 
WHERE username='%s'",
mysql_real_escape_string($username));

// Perform Query
$result = mysql_query($query);

// Check result
// This shows the actual query sent to MySQL, and the error. Useful for debugging.
if (!$result) {
$message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
$message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
die($message);
}

// Use result
// Attempting to print $result won't allow access to information in the resource
// One of the mysql result functions must be used
// See also mysql_result(), mysql_fetch_array(), mysql_fetch_row(), etc.
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo $row['CustNum'];

$custnum = $row['CustNum'];

}

// Free the resources associated with the result set
// This is done automatically at the end of the script
mysql_free_result($result);
?> 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Arndt Automotive</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
background-image: url(Background.png);
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table width="1050" border="0" align="center">
<tr align="center">
<td><img src="Banner.png" width="1050" height="275" alt="Banner" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="1200" height="638" border="0" align="center"    background="backgroundmaybe2.png" " style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-   position: center;&gt;
  &lt;tr align="center">
  <td><table width="1090" height="638" border="0" align="center">
  <tr align="left">
    <td width="225"><table width="225" height="638" border="0" id="Left">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" background="backgroundtable1.png"><p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p><a href="index.php"><img src="Home.png" width="170" height="30" alt="Home"  /></a></p>
          <p><a href="AboutUs.php"><img src="About Us.png" width="170" height="30"  alt="About Us" /></a></p>
          <p><a href="Services.php"><img src="Services.png" width="170" height="30"  alt="Services" /></a></p>
          <p><a href="RecentWork.php"><img src="Recent Work.png" width="170" height="30"  alt="Recent Work" /></a></p>
           <p><a href="Login.php"><img src="My Account.png" width="170" height="30" alt="My Account" /></a></p>
          <p><a href="ContactUs.php"><img src="Contact Us.png" width="170" height="30" alt="Contact Us" /></a></p>
          <p><a href="Promotions.php"><img src="Promotions.png" width="170" height="30" alt="Promotions" /></a></p>
          <p><a href="Location.php"><img src="Location.png" width="170" height="30" alt="Location" /></a></p>
          <p><img src="Hours.png" width="170" height="150" alt="Hours" /></p></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
    <td width="125">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="850"><table width="850" height="638" border="0" background="backgroundtable2.png" >

      <tr>
        <td align="center"><html>

<head>
<title></title>
<script>
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
{
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
return;
} 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
 {
 document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
 }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
</script>

<body>
<?php echo $username?></b>
<?php echo $custnum?></b>




<form>
<select name="dropdown" onChange="showUser(this.value)">
<?php query() ;
?>
</select>
<?php close() ?>
 </form>
 <div id="txtHint"><b>Invoice info will be listed here.</b></div></td>
 <p><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p>

      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  </table></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
 <table width="1050" height="275" border="0" align="center" background="Footer.png">
 <tr>
 <td><table width="950" border="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td width="256" align="left"><a href="http://www.acdelco.com/"><img src="AC Delco Logo.png" width="245" height="47" alt="AC Delco" /></a></td>
    <td width="265" align="center"><a href="http://www.asashop.org/"><img src="ASA Logo.png" width="248" height="115" alt="ASA" /></a></td>
    <td width="141" align="center"><a href="https://www.ase.com/Home.aspx"><img src="ASE Logo.png" width="112" height="115" alt="ASE" /></a></td>
    <td width="270"><a href="http://www.jasperengines.com/index.php"><img src="Jasper Logo.png" width="252" height="81" alt="Jasper" /></a></td>
  </tr>
  </table></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

and this is the source code for getuser.php

```
        <?PHP 
 // Connects to your Database 

 mysql_connect('localhost', 'root') or die(mysql_error()); 

 mysql_select_db("ServiceHistoryDB") or die(mysql_error()); 

 $q=$_GET["q"];
 //This checks to see if there is a page number. If not, it will set it to page 1 

 if (!(isset($pagenum))) 

  { 

 $pagenum = 1; 

 } 


 //Here we count the number of results 

 //Edit $data to be your query 

 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM invoices") or die(mysql_error()); 

 $rows = mysql_num_rows($data); 



 //This is the number of results displayed per page 

 $page_rows = 10; 



 //This tells us the page number of our last page 

 $last = ceil($rows/$page_rows); 



 //this makes sure the page number isn't below one, or more than our maximum pages 

 if ($pagenum < 1) 

 { 

 $pagenum = 1; 

  } 

 elseif ($pagenum > $last) 

 { 

 $pagenum = $last; 

 }  

 //This sets the range to display in our query 

 $max = 'limit ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows; 

 //This is your query again, the same one... the only difference is we add $max into it


 $data_p = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM invoices  WHERE CarNum = '".$q."' $max") or   die(mysql_error()); 


 //This is where you display your query results

  echo "<table border='1'>
 <tr>
 <th>Date</th>
 <th>        Service        </th>
 </tr>";


 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data_p )) 

 { echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" .date('M d Y', strtotime($info['Date'])) . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $info['BriefDescription'] . "</td>";
   echo "<br>";
   echo "</tr>";
   }
  echo "</table>";



  // This shows the user what page they are on, and the total number of pages



  // First we check if we are on page one. If we are then we don't need a link to the previous page or the first page so we do nothing. If we aren't then we generate links to the first page, and to the previous page.

  if ($pagenum == 1) 

 {

 } 

 else 

 {

 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=1'> <<-First</a> ";

 echo " ";

 $previous = $pagenum-1;

 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$previous'> <-Previous</a> ";

 } 


 //just a spacer

 echo " ---- ";


 //This does the same as above, only checking if we are on the last page, and then generating the Next and Last links

 if ($pagenum == $last) 

 {

 } 

 else {

 $next = $pagenum+1;

 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$next'>Next -></a> ";

 echo " ";

 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$last'>Last ->></a> ";

 } 

 ?>
```

Comment: You didn't post any code BTW?

Comment: show us your html and php code for pagination.

Comment: i just got it on there, thank you for the quick replies though

Answer (score 0):

Try out this useful Jquery Plugin.

[Jquery Plugin for data Table](http://datatables.net/)